# Can I change the direction the camera faces when I undock?

Tags: eve-online

Every time I undock from a station the camera faces backwards (relative to my ship) and the first thing I have to do is rotate it to face forwards, is there some way I can make it face forwards by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not - it's the same with jumping through stargates and the camera distance resetting each time you undock.

Camera angle and distance settings have been [requested](https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=posts&t=162592) [many](http://community.eveonline.com/ingameboard.asp?a=topic&threadID=1229227) [times](http://community.eveonline.com/ingameboard.asp?a=topic&threadID=322840) [as](http://community.eveonline.com/ingameboard.asp?a=topic&threadID=203827) [a](http://community.eveonline.com/ingameboard.asp?a=topic&threadID=383745) [feature](http://community.eveonline.com/ingameboard.asp?a=topic&threadID=469397) by the EVE community in the past but as of yet haven't been acted upon by CCP so for now at least we're stuck with manually resetting camera angles and distances each time we jump or undock.